# How to measure thickness of a sunscreen film(nano meters)?

Tags: material-science, spectroscopy, optical-materials

I want to measure the thickness of a sunscreen film. In the current method, I measure the volume of the film and use the area of the substrate to calculate the thickness. But I need a more reliable and experimental method to verify the calculation.

Sunscreen is wet, thick and opaque and I am also in need of a noncontact method. Please suggest me if there are any methods you can think of.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this sunscreen applied to a flat, rigid surface like a granite surface plate? Or to a rough, pliable surface like somebody's skin?

Comment: It's applied on a glass plate (50*50 mm)